# Create a django model for a table imported externally

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, so please excuse if I am totally wrong.

I have a django installation in which some tables are manually imported from outside source. There is one table with large number of fields. In my current django I need to interact with only few of its fields.

Can I create a django model for that table with just the fields I need and will it work? Will it mess up migrations completely? How is such a situation usually handled in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use meta option [db-table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#db-table) and [managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed)

```
class ModelWithFewFields(models.Model):
    # Fields declare here

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Real_DB_TABLE_NAME'
        managed = False
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: glad to help you!

Comment: If you want most of the columns to be present on your model, have a look at Django management command "instpectdb". This may save you some typing :)